# How to visualize binary IVs in logit model simulation?

Tags: data-visualization, simulation

Hello guys and thank you for letting me join this community,

I am working on a logit model and want to display my results with simulation (for clarification I am referring to the style of simulation proposed by Gary King). 
So far I only worked with visualising continuous independent variable, but now my variable of interest is binary, and I am not sure how to visualise it properly and also I am not sure if I set the sequence for my variable  of interest properly (I marked it with #*). I conducted the simulation as follows:

```
beta_hat <- coef(m3)
V_hat <- vcov(m3)
library(MASS)
S <- mvrnorm(1000, beta_hat, V_hat)
mobilecoverage_sim <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 2) #*
scenario <- cbind(1, mobilecoverage_sim, mean(data$totalkia), 
mean(data$propfriendlydeaths), mean(data$popdensity))
Xbeta <- S %*% t(scenario)
p_sim <- (exp(Xbeta))/ (1 + exp(Xbeta))
p_mean <- apply(p_sim, 2, mean)
p_qu <- t(apply(p_sim, 2, quantile, prob = c(0.025, 0.975)))
```

So I have two questions is possible to use simulation in this way for a binary IV and does anyone have a good solution how to visualise it.

I am looking forward to your response

Kind regards
Armin